# How to place an object so that it does not run into walls of my scene in jMonkey

Tags: collision-detection, bounding-box, jmonkeyengine, raycasting, bounding-volume

In my game, the user has to click at a point to place an object (mesh). I can cast a ray and find the horizontal point where the object can be translated and then attached to rootNode to display it. However the problem is that if the user click too near to another object/scene_wall the object to be placed, runs into it. How can I prevent it??

Comment: The new `BetterCharacterControl`ha improved collision detection. You might be able to find techniques there how to use collision detection. You can also add your code to the question so that we can see what you tried.